# Submit a word programmatically where no official API is available

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests

When I visit this page and type a word, I get the expected output.

https://sanskrit.uohyd.ac.in/scl/

Tools - (Sandhi-Splitter) option

Sample text:
योगेश्वरश्च

Correct output:
[योग ईश्वरः च]

I tried this code:

```
import requests
url = "https://sanskrit.uohyd.ac.in/scl/"
text_to_submit = "योगेश्वरश्च"
response = requests.post(url, data={"input": text_to_submit})
print(response.text)
```

But it does not return the expected results.

Comment: What is the request sent when using the website in the browser?

Comment: I don't see anything on that page that accepts input.  Where are you typing your "sample text"?

Comment: I image your "correct output" is the expected results. Why do you think that would be correct?

Comment: Tools - (Sandhi-splitter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a request going in the backend which accepts the input word. It can be done using a POST request with the proper payload. Find the code snippet for the same.

```py
import requests
import urllib.parse

headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Origin': 'https://sanskrit.uohyd.ac.in',
    'Referer': 'https://sanskrit.uohyd.ac.in/scl/',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not(A:Brand";v="24", "Chromium";v="122"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"',
}

# Input word
word = 'योगेश्वरश्च'
data = {
    'word': word,
    'outencoding': 'D',
    'encoding': 'Unicode',
    'mode': 'sent',
}

response = requests.post(
    'https://sanskrit.uohyd.ac.in/cgi-bin/scl/sandhi_splitter/sandhi_splitter.cgi',
    headers=headers,
    data=data,
)

# Converting the response into proper encoding format
final_value = urllib.parse.unquote(response.content)
print(final_value)
```

**Output:**

```html
<div id='finalout' style='border-style:solid; border-width:1px;padding:10px;color:blue;font-size:14px;height:200px'> [योग-ईश्वरः च]
<br /><br /><br />Click <a href="/cgi-bin/SKT/sktgraph.cgi?lex=MW&cache=f&st=t&us=f&font=deva&cp=t&text=yogeSvaraSca&t=WX&topic=&mode=g&pipeline=f">here</a> to see all possible solutions.</div><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be a text box that you typing the Sanskrit word to submit the word.

You cannot directly do a post method to a website you need to put in headers and security infos like tokens and everything.

If you want to do webscrapping use the tools like python-selenium and webdrivers to insert info in that text box and send answers.

And if you need to do it via Rest API then you need to have the appropriate headers or the token that the post url needs to authenticate.